# How to get gcc to report an error for an undefined, unused, external symbol

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm looking for a way to produce a linker error when a function is declared
but not defined in an exported class. Here is a simple example that
illustrates the problem:

test.h:

```
#define DLLEXPORT __attribute__((__visibility__("default")))

class DLLEXPORT CLASS_A {
public:
     CLASS_A();
    ~CLASS_A();
    void withdefinition();
    void nodefinition();
};
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

CLASS_A::CLASS_A() {}
CLASS_A::~CLASS_A() {}
void CLASS_A::withdefinition() {}
```

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fPIC
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--no-undefined

top: test.so

test.o: test.cpp test.h Makefile
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    nm -C test.o

test.so: test.o
    g++ -shared $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@
    nm -C test.so
```

The output that I see from "nm test.o" is the following:

```
nm -C test.o
0000000000000014 T withdefinition()
0000000000000000 T CLASS_A::CLASS_A()
0000000000000000 T CLASS_A::CLASS_A()
000000000000000a T CLASS_A::~CLASS_A()
000000000000000a T CLASS_A::~CLASS_A()
```

The function "withdefinition()" generates an external definition, while the function "nodefinition()" generates no symbol at all. In theory, if the compilation of test.cpp could generate an undefined symbol for "nodefinition" the subsequent link command would complain about the undefined symbol. Unfortunately, this only happens if "nodefinition()" is explicitly called in the code. This is an error that can commonly occur during refactoring and it would be helpful if it could be detected as early as possible - is there an easy way to do this automatically with the gcc toolchain?

Comment: Certainly, using unit tests would detect the problem. But my actual use case for this is in a large existing codebase that does not have unit tests for all exported classes - and implementing them to detect this kind of problem would be cumbersome and time consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A (non-virtual) function declared but not defined produces no trace in the compiled code. This is by design. You cannot change it because such change will break absolutely everything.

Imagine every function, every class, every piece of data, every little nothing you have in the standard `include` files that you don't use, don't care about and don't even know it exists leaving a symbol in your compiled code.

Comment: You're correct - making it a virtual function does cause an error to be reported: "undefined reference to `vtable for CLASS_A'"

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler doesn't actually KNOW which functions you are defining where, it's impossible for the compiler/linker to perform this task.

Note that the knowledge that there may be a function called `nodefinition` is lost during the compilation phase, so this information is only retained if you actually USE the function somewhere.

You could possibly write some (or find someone else's already written) code-analysis tool using the clang analysing framework, if you have a strict "x.h" and "x.cpp" relationship, so no functionality declared in "x.h" is ever defined in another file than "x.cpp" (or files included by "x.cpp"). But if the implementation is allowed elsewhere, then it's only possible to detect when the function is actually needed by the linker.

Of course, code-review should also catch this sort of problem in most cases.

Comment: Conceptually, it seems that the compiler should know this, since I've instructed it to export the class using __attribute__((__visibility__("default"))) and also given the -fvisibility=hidden flag, implying that anything declared in the externally visible class should have a definition by link time.

Comment: "should have a definition by link time". This attribute doesn't require a definition (in what file it should be required?) It says that *when and if* a definition is encountered, it should be exported.

Comment: Again, theoretically (since it clearly doesn't work this way) the attribute could cause it to generate a "U" symbol in all modules that include "test.h", which the linker would either consolidate into a single "U" symbol (if no definition was found) or a "T" symbol (when there is a single definition). It wouldn't really matter which file the definition was in.

Comment: @ajclinto: You might find `used` attribute also  interesting (emphasis mine):  "This attribute, attached to a function, means that code **must be emitted** for the function even if it appears that the function is not referenced. This is useful, for example, when the function is referenced only in inline assembly.". However I am not sure yet how practically it provides possibility to force `"U"` symbol.

Comment: My original testing showed that none of these attributes affected the symbols in test.o: noinline, used, weak, externally_visible